# Unrecognized selector sent to instance on constructor

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I am getting the famous `"unrecognized selector sent to instance"` on my constructor. Potentially something very simple I am missing.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Problem on the next line:

    UserFetcher* userFetcher = [[UserFetcher alloc] initWithEmail:[self email] AndPassword:[self password]]; 

    [userFetcher fetch];
}
```

**UserFetcher.h**

```
-(id)initWithEmail:(NSString*)theEmail AndPassword:(NSString*)thePassword;

-(void)fetch;
```

**UserFetcher.m**

```
-(id)initWithEmail:(NSString*)theEmail AndPassword:(NSString*)thePassword AndDelegate: (id<UserFetcherDelegate>)theDelegate;
{
    if ([super init])
    {
        email = theEmail;
        password = thePassword;
    }
    return self;
}


-(void) fetch {...}
```

**Error**

```
2012-07-14 22:15:12.726 Project1[38478:c07] -[UserFetcher initWithEmail:AndPassword:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7af2ff0
```

Any ideas what is missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot the `AndDelegate: (id<UserFetcherDelegate>)theDelegate;` part. Also, remove the `;` from the end of the line (in the implementation). Should probably be:

```
-(id)initWithEmail:(NSString*)theEmail AndPassword:(NSString*)thePassword
{
    if ([super init])
    {
        email = theEmail;
        password = thePassword;
    }
    return self;
}
```